# How to identify Int dates formats in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a single date type field in MongoDB named **invoiceDate** which contains two types of data formats

1. ISO standard "2019-07-27T09:01:15.598Z"
2. Epoch "575288179200000"

I want to extract/identify all invoice Ids which contain the Epoch date format only. How can I write Mongodb Query for that?

Comment: You can use the aggregation operator [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html) to get the data type of the field value. In your case, the types might return as `date` and `double` (or `string`, in case the values are in quotes).

Comment: Data type is date for both

Comment: How did you create the date value as _ISODate_ and _milliseconds since Epoch_ formats for the same field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about check if it is a number or not first. For eg.

```js
const date = "575288179200000";
if (!Number.isNaN(date)) {
//Epoch 
} else {
//ISO standard
}
```

Comment: How can i automate this process? How to all invoices related this type of dates?

Comment: This should do the trick.
`
db.invoices.find({$where: function() {return !Number.isNaN(this.invoiceDate)}})
`